# Set screen brightness of Acer All in One PC

Tags: display, brightness, all-in-one

I have an Acer All in One PC (it is an Acer Aspire Z3771), which I currently use as an ordinary monitor. It does not have any external buttons to change its screen settings, and if I start it as a PC (currently with Windows 8 RP installed), I cannot change the screen brightness from the Power settings either.

Is there any way I can change the screen brightness?

Comment: Function(Fn) key + Up arrow doesnt work?

Comment: This is an all in one PC with an external USB keyboard, not a laptop, so it does not have Fn key. However I expected it to _work_ like a laptop in a way that its brightness can be set in the Control Panel, however it can't.

Comment: Hmm, that is true... But all in one usually have a side button that implements all FN keys on it...(at least on the models that I know)

Answer (score 1):

To Adjust Brightness on an Acer All-in-One Desktop

1. At bottom R.H. corner of screen, click on up-arrow to "Show Hidden Icons."
2. Click on "Color32 bpp" etc.
3. Under "Desktops and Displays" click "My Digital Flat Panel."
4. Click "Display Color."
5. "AMD VISIONControl Center" panel appears, to enable setting Brightness, among others.
   or
   "Show Hidden Icons"  >  "Color32bpp"  > "Desktops & Displays" > "My Digital Flat Panel"  > 
   "Display Color" >

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Windows 8 yet, but you could download this software:[DimScreen](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/DimScreen.shtml), and add the shortcut to the Windows Startup folder (does Windows 8 have one?)
On login into windows, it decreases brightness by default to 50%. But you can click on its icon in the system tray (is there a system tray in Windows 8?), and set a desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to adjust the brightness on your All-In-One desktop with Windows 8:

1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen to open your Charms and
   select Search.
2. Type Graphics in the search box and select settings.
3. Tap or click Intel® Graphics and Media from the results.
4. Tap or click OK.
5. Under Display, select Color Enhancement.
6. On the right, drag the Brightness bar left or right to adjust your
   brightness.
7. Tap or click OK to save your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I done; I have Windows 7 though so I'm not sure if it'll work.

Go to the Start Menu. Type "Brightness Settings" into the search bar. Click on "Adjust screen brightness' under 'Control Panel'. Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to change the settings from Windows on the device (assuming the original Acer software is installed)

On an ACER  Aspire Z3771. Similar to the previous answer. Try the following:

on the left of the date stamp ( located on the lower right corner of the screen ) you'll see a small up-pointing triangle .

Left click on the triangle and , hover the mouse over the items until you find : Intel ( R ) HD graphics icon. Left click on the icon.

You should see: INTEL GRAPHICS and MEDIA COTROL PANEL, also  the Intel Logo.

From the menu above the Panel, select GRAPHICS PROPERTIES … by a left click on it.

Select one of the following APPLICATION MODE :  BASIC MODE ( click on the corresponding circle on the left and you should see a dot into ). Click OK.

On the new opened Panel, below DISPLAY is a COLOR ENHANCEMENT with 2 right - pointing triangles. Left click on it. Move the cursors ( dots ) by clicking on each of the 5 options  , and holding then  moving to the right-left as you wish , until you reach the desired display brightness ( uncheck the PREVIEW - if you want to and record the figures beside each adjustment for future reference ) and , finally click OK.

Follow the same steps if you want to RESET or just left-click on RESTORE DEFAULTS to have the factory settings.

Comment: Maybe mention since it's Windows 8, to go to the Desktop mode first...?